# How to Apply Sorting on Selection column in DevExtreme Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I am using `DevExtreme` Grid in `C# MVC` to display data in View. Now I want to apply `sorting` functionality on First column that is `Selection` column as you can see in below image.

[image: Grid View]

Now, I need to make select column sort-able (selected and non-selected). Means when user first time click on header it will display all selected rows first and then non-selected and vice-versa.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Since the "select" column is not a data column, you cannot sort data by this column.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a way to do this, 
I found this ticket in [devexpress support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T581204/dxdatagrid-sort-by-selected-rows)

As you can see in the example, they used a javascript function to do a custom sort:

```
sortingMethod(value1: any, value2: any) {
  var isSelected1 = this.dataGrid.instance.isRowSelected(value1),
      isSelected2 = this.dataGrid.instance.isRowSelected(value2);

  if(isSelected1 && !isSelected2) return -1;
  if(!isSelected1 && isSelected2) return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

And in the column "CustomerId" just used the function above

```
<dxi-column 
      dataField="CustomerId"
      sortOrder="asc"
      [visible]="false"
      [sortingMethod]="sortingMethod"
      ></dxi-column>
```